# Nginx server not restarting

Tags: linux, nginx, google-cloud-platform, debian

I'm using this [instance image](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/jetware/wordpress4-lemp7) from Google Cloud Platform Marketplace. This instance is from [Jetware](https://jetware.io) [#jetware](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%23jetware).

The server is configured with load balancer, reverse proxy and http cache.

I want to install SSL certificate for which it require me to restart nginx server.

I did so by executing the following command:

`sudo systemctl restart nginx`

I'm getting the following error:

```
Failed to restart nginx.service: Unit nginx.service not found.
```

When I run this command to check the status of nginx:

```
sudo systemctl status nginx.service
```

I got the following message:

```
Unit nginx.service could not be found.
```

Then I ran this:

```
nginx -t
```

I got the following message:

```
nginx: the configuration file /jet/etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /jet/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

I further ran this:

```
ps -aux | grep nginx
```

And got the following output:

```
<logged in user id>    1259  0.0  0.1  91720  1548 ?        Ss   06:46   0:00 nginx: master process /jet/bin/nginx
<logged in user id>    1262  0.0  0.4  92184  4748 ?        S    06:46   0:00 nginx: worker process
<logged in user id>    3329  0.0  0.2  10984  2272 pts/0    S+   08:07   0:00 grep nginx
```

So why is nginx not restarting, is there a way to restart nginx?

Comment: I somehow posted first here. Will be posting in appropriate site next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on Xubunut 18.04, this might not work 1:1 for you)
The service which started your nginx is not called nginx. Have you started nginx manually? This is rather a systemd thing than a nginx problem I think.
=> You need to find which service started the nginx

```
systemctl status $(pidof nginx)
```

If this stays empty you don't started nginx with a service. You could create one or should be able to get one from your distr.
If this shows a list you can sanity check (or simply try) which one is the right one to restart (on my system some sub-processes are also printed)

Some Info:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225802/finding-systemd-unit-owning-a-running-daemon-process
https://serverfault.com/questions/692771/find-the-location-of-a-systemd-service

Comment: Thanks, this led me to get some more hints and I finally found the way to restart nginx server. Instead 0f using systemctl restart nginx, we have to use "restart nginx"

Answer (score 0):

Found the correct way to restart by going to this link: http://jetware.io/appliances/jetware/wordpress4_lemp7/profile

Jump to Service Control section

Services control

Available services: cron exim monit mysqld nginx php-fpm

Start all services: start

Stop all services:  stop

Service commands:   available|enabled|disabled|enable|disable|start|stop|status|restart servicename

As per the above service control command options, I tried this:

```
restart nginx
```

So instead of using **systemctl restart nginx** or **service restart nginx**, simply use "**restart nginx**". You can also do "**reload nginx**"